# On hover table cell, highlight all respective cell/rows according row height of the hovered cell

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I am trying to create a schedule table using VueJS. Where different columns represent venues with different event duration and each row represents 5min time each.

Duration difference is done by providing a row span to the cell.

```
 <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th class="col">Col One</th>
      <th class="col">Col Two</th>
      <th class="col">Col Three</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>10:00 am</td>
      <td rowspan="3">Event 1</td>
      <td rowspan="4">Event 2</td>
      <td rowspan="6">Event 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10:05 am</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10:10 am</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10:15 am</td>
      <td rowspan="3">Event 4</td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10:20 am</td>
      <td rowspan="4">Event 5</td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10:25 am</td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10:30 am</td>
      <td rowspan="3">Event 7</td>
      <td rowspan="6">Event 6</td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10:35 am</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10:40 am</td>
      <td rowspan="4">Event 9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10:45 am</td>
      <td rowspan="3">Event 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10:50 am</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10:55 am</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11:00 am</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Each event is highlighted using the Hover effect

```
tbody td:hover {
  transform: scale(1) !important;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1) !important;
  -moz-transform: scale(1) !important;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(13, 84, 139, 0.3) !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(13, 84, 139, 0.3) !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(13, 84, 139, 0.3) !important;
}
```

The start time of the event is hight lighted using the first-child hover effect

```
tbody tr:hover td:first-child {
  background-color: rgb(119, 160, 190) !important;
  color: #fff !important;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

My requirement is to highlight the time cells from start time to end time. Need to add a hover effect to the first td cells which comes under row-height of the hovered td cell.  Is there any way to do this using CSS?

If not possible suggest any way to do this using the VueJS DOM selection techniques.

[Codepen Sample HTML and CSS](https://codepen.io/shafeequeom/pen/abmNGbJ)

Thanks in advance

Comment: you may dispatch a pseudo element hover the first col drawn from the hovered cell : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/xxEVzLM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(while waiting for a feedback)

You may use a translucide  pseudo  drawn from the hovered  cell and lay it hover the cells in front in the first column.

Javascript and custom CSS can help you simplify the code from the [demo idea  i linked earlier](https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/xxEVzLM).

```js
function highlightTimeEvent() {
let tdcol = document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr td:not(:first-child)");
[...tdcol].forEach((td) => {
  td.style.setProperty("--offset", td.offsetLeft * -1 + "px");
  // console.log(td.style.getPropertyValue("--offset")); //check it out if any doubt

});
}

window.onload=highlightTimeEvent;
window.onresize=highlightTimeEvent;
```

```css
table {
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin:auto;
}

table th {
  background: #2c3b46;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
  color: aliceblue;
  width: 150px;
}

table tr td {
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px;
  padding: 7px 0px 7px 0px;
}

tbody td:hover {
  transform: scale(1) !important;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1) !important;
  -moz-transform: scale(1) !important;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(13, 84, 139, 0.3) !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(13, 84, 139, 0.3) !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(13, 84, 139, 0.3) !important;
}


/*
tbody tr:hover td:first-child {
  background-color: rgb(119, 160, 190) !important;
  color: #fff !important;
  font-weight: bold;
}*/

tbody td {
  border-right: rgba(63, 63, 63, 0.507) 1px solid !important;
}

tbody td~td:hover:before {
  content: "";
  background: rgba(0, 125, 255, 0.25);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  left: var(--offset);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th class="col">Col One</th>
      <th class="col">Col Two</th>
      <th class="col">Col Three</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>10:00 am</td>
      <td rowspan="3">Event 1</td>
      <td rowspan="4">Event 2</td>
      <td rowspan="6">Event 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10:05 am</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10:10 am</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10:15 am</td>
      <td rowspan="3">Event 4</td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10:20 am</td>
      <td rowspan="4">Event 5</td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10:25 am</td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10:30 am</td>
      <td rowspan="3">Event 7</td>
      <td rowspan="6">Event 6</td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10:35 am</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10:40 am</td>
      <td rowspan="4">Event 9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10:45 am</td>
      <td rowspan="3">Event 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10:50 am</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10:55 am</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11:00 am</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </tr>
</table>
```

codepen to play with  :  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ExgKRMz